# swig converts a positive long to negative int

Tags: python, type-conversion, swig

I have code in python that integrates c++ code using swig.
The c++ class has a field with the long value 1393685280 which is converted to python.
The problem is that when calling the getter of this field from python I get the int value -2901282016 instead.
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is not the signedness. The two numbers really look quite unrelated.

Comment: That's odd because _1393685280_ is smaller than what an `int` can store. Can you post the field definition(from SWIG) and initialization, and also the operations attempted from Python?

Comment: It is odd. Let's say I have class MyClass with the public method long getField1(). In the i file I only exported the class (%include "MyClass.h"). Swig generated the method: SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_MyClass_getField1(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) in the wrapper cxx file, and in the py file it generated the method: def getField1(self): return _myobjects.MyClass_getField1(self). From python I call the method mc.getField1() where mc is an object of type MyClass.

Comment: To make it even more weird- the same class has long field "field2" which is defined exactly the same, and contains the value 1393705320. When calling the method mc.getField2() from python I get the int 1393705320.

Comment: In addition, the problem only occurs when MyClass is created in the c++ code, when I create an instance of MyClass from python with the same values and then call getField1() from python I receive the right value.

Comment: You mean that when creating the instance from c++ you get the wrong `getField1()` and the right `getField2()`? Are you sure that when creating the class from c++ the `field1` is initialized?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. I'm sure it is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry to give everyone the run-around on this one. 
We found the solution and it's completely unrelated to SWIG. 
Problem emanated from the ODBC driver for the Vertica DB we were using which behaved unpredictably when using a long variable to bind the SQL result to.

Tomer and Inbal